# biblatex-chicago etoolbox error: Invalid boolean Expression

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, etoolbox

I am using bibtex as the backend for my biblatex bibliography but there seems to be some clash between it and the `etoolbox` package that I don't understand. This is on a fresh install of TeXlive 2014. The error only appears if the following conditions are met:

1: BibTeX is the backend
2: I am using biblatex-chicago (there's no tag for that - sorry!)
3: A bib entry is cited twice in the same paragraph

A minimal example follows (in which I have embedded the bibliography in the file for the sake of keeping it simple - doing it this way didn't change the error).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}  
@book{smith_john_1970,  
    address = {City},  
    edition = {1st},  
    title = {Help},  
    publisher = {A. N. Other},  
    author = {Smith, John},  
    year = {1970},  
}  
\end{filecontents}  

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}  
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[732]{smith_john_1970} and \cite[732]{smith_john_1970}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where does `etoolbox` come in within your MWE?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The error I get is `! Package etoolbox Error: Invalid boolean expression.` I get no error when the backend is Biber.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I confirm that... I have not looked into the `biblatex-chicago` file so far.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try the example. Yes biber works (which is why I listed bibtex as a condition) but it would be a real headache for me to make that switch (for unrelated reasons).

Comment: Doesn't `biblatex-chicago` require `biber` now? Or is that just for one of its formats still? EDIT: OK. It is not a requirement if you use the notes format. But it restricts the features you can use: 'I also strongly encourage all users who haven’t already done
so to switch to Biber as their backend; it has long been a requirement for the
author-date styles, but it is now becoming indispensable for accessing all the
features of the notes & bibliography style, as well.' (p 1 of the documentation)

Comment: Since the 'notes' style is not yet fully dependent on `biber`, you should file a bug report.  The developer has always been quite responsive in times past.  (Note, however, that `biber` seems poised to become a requirement for `biblatex-chicago`.  Note also that `biber` is quite good at converting to and from BibTeX-compliant bibliographies, which may prove useful to you.)

Comment: Hmm. For me it works perfectly. It could be a version issue. Does bibtex8 make a difference?

Comment: @penguinpreferred It is indeed an issue introduced by a fairly recent change ([2014-03-22](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/47edd0899b68edef3e4191f27209e14e5b40396a)) and as such has only made its way to (I think I'm right in saying) version 2.9 and 2.9a, furthermore this issue really only only occurs when using BibTeX or BibTeX8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one does some digging in `chicago-notes.cbx`, in the definition for the `cite` bibmacro one finds

```
\ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}}%
    or
    (
    togl {blx@skipbiblist}%
    and
    togl {cms@inheritshhand}%
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{crossref}}%
    )
  }
```

And indeed that seems to be the boolean expression that causes `etoolbox` to get the hiccups. 
All but one of these conditions are completely fine, the problem arises from `togl {blx@skipbiblist}`.

`skipbiblist` is - like its friends`skipbib` and `skiplab` - a Biber-only option (unfortunately, `skipbiblist` is quite new and not documented in the docs, it is an extension of `skiplos` and works in similar fashion to its "friends", see p. 62 §3.1.3.2 *Type/Entry Options* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

If you do not use Biber, but BibTeX or BibTeX8, the file `biblatex1.sty` is loaded (with Biber it would be `biblatex2.sty`), `biblatex1.sty`, however does not have a definition for `blx@skipbiblist` (it does provide one for `blx@skipbib`, `blx@skiplos` and `blx@skiplab` though - so it rather [seems like a `biblatex1` bug for me](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/267)) and therefore the conditional is invalid for `etoolbox`, because `blx@skipbiblist` does not exist if you do not use Biber.

## But I want a fix now!

There are two fixes for this issue

### 1. Use Biber

Just use Biber as your backend, enjoy all its functionalities and capabilities and get rid of this little bug; you merely have to pass `backend=biber` as loading-time option to `biblatex`/`biblatex-chicago` (and obviously have Biber installed and run it instead of BibTeX).

That is the preferred solution, see for example page 1 (!) of [the `biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf):

> I also strongly encourage all users who haven’t already done so to
>   switch to Biber as their backend; it has long been a requirement for
>   the author-date styles, but it is now becoming indispensable for
>   accessing all the features of the notes & bibliography style, as well.

Or

### 2. Provide the missing toggle yourself

Just put

```
\providetoggle{blx@skipbiblist}
```

into your preamble.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}  
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\providetoggle{blx@skipbiblist}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilde} and \cite{wilde}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have filed a bug report [`biblatex` bug tracker #267: skipbiblist vs skiplos](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/267), in the meantime you can use one of the two fixes above.

Comment: You have to put a `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother`after the `\providetoggle`.

Comment: @Sveinung no you haven't :)

Comment: `blx@skiplos` has now been internally renamed to `blx@skibiblist` ([e9f4f3d](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/e9f4f3d2cfc398dc2e8ab6fb187e83ff2b0a12bb)) so with the upcoming version of `biblatex` that issue should be resolved.

Comment: @cgnieder Correct, you haven't, why not? Because it is not executed?

Comment: @Sveinung because at some point the argument must be placed between `\csname ... \endcsname`. They build the command name from the whole (expanded) argument,  also with catcode 12 tokens...

Comment: @cgnieder To advanced for me, maybe I shall convert my comment to a new question.