# etoolbox error when using uni-wtal-ger style

Tags: biblatex, biber, etoolbox

I get an error when I try to use the [`uni-wtal-ger` citation style](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-wtal-ger) and since I am fairly new to Latex I am unable to make sense of it (at all).

My usepackage declaration for biblatex looks like this:

```
\usepackage[
citestyle=uni-wtal-ger,
bibstyle=authortitle,
sorting=nty,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

This works for all citation styles I tried, including `uni-wtal-lin`, but not for `uni-wtal-ger`, which throws the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `edtranslog' on page 3 undefined on input line 60.

! Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifbbx:annotation' undefined.
```

This seems similar to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200409/biblatex-chicago-etoolbox-error-invalid-boolean-expression) but the proposed solution there is to use biber which I already do. Any help is much appreciated.

(Dist: Arch Linux with texlive-most, texlive-lang and texlive-bibtexextra)

Comment: The style looks a bit old, notifiy the maintainer, perhaps they need to update it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thx, I contacted the maintainer.

Comment: Unless you know exactly why you are doing it, it is usually recommended not to use separate `bibstyle` and `citestyle` instructions, but load a single style with `style`. In your case `citestyle=uni-wtal-ger, bibstyle=authortitle,` should probably just become `style=uni-wtal-ger,`. `biblatex` allows you to select different citation and bibliography styles, but not all styles support the free 'mix-and-match-approach'. Some custom styles work under the assumption that both bibliography and citation style are set to the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uni-wtal-ger` is depending on `biblatex-dw`. Like many other custom styles, the citation and bibliography styles included in those packages are mutually dependent. So mixing `uni-wtal-ger` or `biblatex-dw` with other styles will lead to errors.

The style does still work perfectly when using it completely as `citestyle` and `bibstyle` though.

So please try

```
\usepackage[
style=uni-wtal-ger,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: thank you very much, everything is working now!